# Magento 2 - Include Custom Attribute to Email Template

Tags: attributes, magento2

I want add Attributes that are on the Product to an Email Template - for example - a custom attribute I have added to appear on the shipping email template.
I have successfully added a new template and that is working fine - I just can't 'get' the infomation on to it.
For example - I have added both: (for the attribute eco_collection

{{var order.getEcoCollection()}}

{{var EcoCollection|raw}}

to no effect.

Comment: Did you find any solution on this? Have a similar need